# Что означают эти ошибки и как их исправить?

Tags: flutter

Compiler message:
/D:/Install/Flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_chips_input-1.9.0-dev.3/lib/src/chips_input.dart:393:3: Error: Type 'AutofillScope' not found.
AutofillScope get currentAutofillScope => null;
^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Compiler message:
/D:/Install/Flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_chips_input-1.9.0-dev.3/lib/src/chips_input.dart:393:3: Error: Type 'AutofillScope' not found.
AutofillScope get currentAutofillScope => null;
^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception: Errors during snapshot creation: null
build failed.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'D:\Install\Flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 882
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'D:\Install\Flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 32s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

это урок из ютуба, код взят от сюда https://bitbucket.org/mbalychev/maxfit_livecode/src/lesson8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема с плагином [flutter_chips_input](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_chips_input#-readme-tab-), скорее всего из-за `1.9.0-dev.3` версии.

Зайдите в файл `pubspec.yaml` и замените строчку:

> flutter_chips_input: 1.9.0-dev.1

на

> flutter_chips_input: ^1.8.3

Выполните команду в консоли: `flutter pub get`.
И запустите проект.